# Problem with fetch and blob in JavaScript when getting an image from Camera in Capacitor

Tags: javascript, android, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm having difficulties with the variable res in my code. After making a request with fetch to obtain an image from image.webPath, the value of res is an empty object ({}). This unexpected behavior prevents me from obtaining the Blob type I need to work with the image.

```
const image = await Camera.getPhoto({
  quality: 100,
  resultType: CameraResultType.Uri,
  direction: CameraDirection.Rear,
  source: CameraSource.Photos
});

const res = await fetch(image.webPath!);
console.log("1" + res);
console.log("1.1" + JSON.stringify(res));

const blob = await res.blob();
console.log(JSON.stringify(blob));
```

Why is res empty instead of containing the expected image? How can I solve this issue and obtain the correct Blob type from the fetch response? I would appreciate any guidance or solutions that can help me resolve this problem.

Comment: `res` is a `Response` object, it does not represent the image. `blob` you should be a `Blob` object that represents the image. Using `JSON.stringify()` doesn't really make much sense since those objects are not meant to be used as JSON data.